# How to secure SQL Server Management Studtio

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, authorization, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on client systems. We got information that some people just open the Management Studio and change the data.

How can we stop from this happening and can we make a log of what is being changed by them?

Comment: An additional measure you could take would be a [logon trigger that checks `APPNAME`](http://www.erichumphrey.com/category/sql-triggers/) but this is settable by the client so cannot be relied upon except to thwart some people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not get the idea of `runas`
.But i used @Martin Smith idea 
and build solution which is below.

It will be used to disable all **non sa user** doing any activity in any login. 
I did not test it in active directory.

1. Deny Write
2. Deny Read
3. Deny Any Database
4. Deny Sql to connect.

   ```
   Create TRIGGER DisableSMSSEntry_trigger
   ON ALL SERVER  WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
   FOR LOGON

   AS

       BEGIN
       DECLARE @NtUserName AS NVARCHAR(100)

       IF ( (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(nt_user_name)) AS LogedUser  FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND login_name !='sa') >0 )
       BEGIN
       SET @NtUserName= (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(nt_domain+'\'+nt_user_name)) AS LogedUser  FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND login_name !='sa')



       DECLARE @membername  AS varchar(100),@rolename AS varchar(100)
       SET @membername=@NtUserName
       set @rolename ='DB_DenyDataWriter'
       EXEC sp_addrolemember @membername,@rolename
       set @rolename = 'DB_DenyDataReader'
       EXEC sp_addrolemember @membername,@rolename

       exec  (' DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO '+ @NtUserName )
       exec  ('DENY SQL CONNECT ' + @NtUserName )
       ROLLBACK
       END

   END
   ```

Answer (score 4):

> how can we stop from this happening

Change the logins on your SQL Server. The users can only connect to databases and servers that they have the credentials for.

If you are using windows login for authentication, you will need to run whatever application that needs the database using its own login (using [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) or such), again, only giving access to the application.

Comment: is there possibility that we can **disable** Windows authentication in sql server management studio and when our tech need to login he may **enable** windows authentication.

Comment: @faheemkhan - I am not aware of such a possibility.